# Including "-" in Youtue API's phrase search

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube users write video titles like

```
artistname - songname
```

like

```
Eminem - Soldiers
```

So, if I want to search ARTIST (not song) named `Love`, I will have to search `Love -`

I tried

```
max-results=1&q=intitle:"Love -"&orderby=viewCount&restriction=US
```

or equivalently

```
max-results=1&q=intitle:%22Love%20-%22&orderby=viewCount&restriction=US
```

But then it gives videos like

```
Eminem - Love The Way You Lie ft. Rihanna
```

which contains `-` and `Love`, but doesn't contain `Love -`

Is there any way I can code it? I currently trying Java, but if including `-` only works in another language, then I am willing to change language.

**Alternative plan**

Alternatively, if I can make something like "search video title that has `Love` and `-` but `-` comes later than `Love` " that will be good too.

Then video titles like `Love you - blahblah` will be also searched, because `-` appears after `Love`, but `Eminem - Love the way you lie` won't be search, because `-` appears earlier than `Love`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using this:

```
    GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

From the youtube docs:

The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.

Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.